# Shortcut to change the gnome-terminal font size

Tags: shortcut-keys, fonts, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I need fast shortcut to change the terminal font size. I use `gnome-terminal`.

I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> but the size is not changed.

Is there another shortcut? Can I add a shortcut like this?

Comment: Tip:  `+` = `shift` + `=`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> are working fine for me. Maybe you have different shortcuts configured.

To change the keyboard shortcuts, go to *Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts...* in the gnome-terminal menu, and look for *Zoom In* and *Zoom Out*:

[image]

Comment: LOL, ctrl - is working for me but ctrl + is not, fml

Comment: ctrl+shift++ is working for me :)

Comment: @AlexanderMills Note that on US keyboards, the `+` is on the `=` key, so you actually have to hit `shift` and `=` to get a `+`. This is probably why you have to use `ctrl`+`shift`+`+` (or actually, it is `ctrl`+`shift`+`=`). If you don't like this, just configure some other keyboard shortcut as described above. For instance if you configure `ctrl`+`=` to zoom in, you will be able to hit the keys you expected in the first place to zoom in (without `shift`).

Comment: It was so fun to see HUGE and TINY letters on the terminal!!

Comment: On my system, I have to use the + and - keys from the main keyboard. The ones of the numerical keypad do not work in this context.

Answer (score 24):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>for increasing

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> for decreasing font size.

Note: the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is needed on some systems.

Comment: Could you add details how this is different from what the OP tried?

Comment: +1 to Felix Francis...Thanks this solution worked for me.

Comment: @  Volker Siegel - The difference is of using the "Shift" key

Comment: note that "+" is 2nd level key. "=" is 1lvl

Comment: Both of these work on Ubuntu. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Trick that worked for me was to use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `=` or `Ctrl` + `-` but NOT on numeric keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for this precision which still helps in 2021 :)

Answer (score 4):

Remember that terminal is VERY literal! The + key Ubuntu terminal wants is on top row and requires Shift otherwise it's =.

Comment: That may be the problem - but it depends a lot on the locale or language settings.